# How to convert MySQL JSON array to comma separated string and link to related value

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I have following id in column

```
 [1,2]
```

which the account of ID 1 is Kenvin, and ID2 is Charles
How can i get the info like this in a new column:

```
['Kenvin','charles']
```

table A

| id | account |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | kenvin |
| 2. | charles |

table B

| id | title | target | table_a_ids |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 4 | [1,2] |
| 2 | xyz | 1 | [] |
| 3 | ggg | 4 | [2] |

target output: (add a display columns as table_a_accounts in table B)

| id | title | target | table_a_ids | table_a_accounts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 4. | [1,2] | ['kenvin','charles'] |
| 2 | xyz | 1 | [] | [] |
| 3 | ggg | 4 | [2] | ['charles'] |

Comment: Convertion not needed. `WHERE table2.id MEMBER OF table1.array`

Comment: @Akina nono..
for example..
in table1, 
column id >>1 , 2, 
column name >> kenvin, charles.

in table 2,
column id >> 1,
column  target_id >> [1,2].

How can i get a new column in table 2 which display as ['kenvin','charles']

Comment: Show this everything in the question text. As code-formatted CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, and desired output as formatted table.

Comment: @Akina please take a look again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT B.id, B.title, B.target, B.table_a_ids, 
       JSON_ARRAYAGG(A.account) table_a_accounts
FROM B
LEFT JOIN A ON A.id MEMBER OF (B.table_a_ids)
GROUP BY B.id, B.title, B.target, B.table_a_ids
```

If your server is 5.7 then use

```sql
SELECT B.id, B.title, B.target, B.table_a_ids, 
       JSON_ARRAYAGG(A.account) table_a_accounts
FROM B
LEFT JOIN A ON JSON_CONTAINS(CAST(B.table_a_ids AS JSON), CAST(A.id AS JSON))
GROUP BY B.id, B.title, B.target, B.table_a_ids
```

If `B.table_a_ids` is JSON datatype then remove according CAST().

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&rdbms2=mysql_5.7&fiddle=9aaac43c22b4d82d2752df8d87f221a0

If `[null]` is not safe for you then use REPLACE().